# integrate sharepoint authentication with office 365

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, integrate, office365

How can i integrate Sharepoint authentication into my BPOS setup? i want users to login to Sharepoint using the same credentials they use to login to BPOS. This is to avoid having to use seperate FBA for Sharepoint 2010.

Do note that the Sharepoint i used is Sharepoint 2010 enterprise  and not Sharepoint Online.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on your scenario and if you are using identity federation.

If you are federating your identities to the cloud/office365 using DirSync then you have SSO to both on-premise and SSO.

If you only have MSOnline users, ie no AD on-premise or at least not syncing it, then you need to set up your on-premise SP2010 with claims support and set up a trust relationship with the Office365/SPOL STS. (At the moment since Office 365 is in private beta and under NDA - that's about what I dare to share...but it's doable)

Comment: thanks for this ..with dirsync must my Active Directory be online 247? This is the scenario i am trying to avoid..i guess dir sync will sync my AD Data periodically and persist it online..Is this correct?